# Easy Way to Perform C# Null Check in a Type Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I am doing some quick type conversions in a project I am not that very familiar with.

They look similar to this:

```
var NewType = new
{
    NewTypeId = old.SubType == null ? 0 : old.SubType.SubTypeId ?? 0,
    OtherType = old.OtherType ?? "",
    Review = old.CustomerComments ?? "",
    Country = old.Country == null ? "" : old.Country.Abbreviation ?? "",
    Customer = old.SubType == null ? "" :
                    old.SubType.Customer == null ? "" :
                        old.SubType.Customer.Name ?? ""
};
```

The objects I'm converting are usually Entity Framework objects. I also don't have the ability to modify the classes I will be converting form.

Is there an easier way to check for nulls, specifically for situations like this where any of the sub-objects could be null?

```
OldType.SubType.AnotherSubType.SomeProperty
```

Comment: What version of .NET (namely C#) are you using?

Comment: C# 5 (.Net 4.5)

Comment: Can you create the new type directly from `IQueryable`? (I.e. projection) You won't need null checks then.

Comment: @rory.ap .NET version is irrelevant; C# version is the important thing.  .NET version and C# version are completely separate from each other.

Comment: @GertArnold Hmm, I will have to think about that. I have an object that is already created which I am using for the conversion but I could possibly do something like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

Since C# 6 you can use the [null-propagation/null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
var NewType = new
{
    NewTypeId = old.SubType?.SubTypeId ?? 0,
    OtherType = old.OtherType ?? "",
    Review = old.CustomerComments ?? "",
    Country = old.Country?.Abbreviation ?? "",
    Customer = old.SubType?.Customer?.Name ?? ""
};
```

---

If you have a class like

```
public class Example
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

and an instance

```
Example sample = GetExample();
```

then this expression:

```
sample?.Value
```

returns a `Nullable<int>`. And that has the value of `Value` if `sample` was not `null` or has no value (is `null`) if `sample` was `null`.

Comment: Not in expressions though.

Comment: @IvanStoev right, forgot that, maybe because OP did not explicitly mention that it needs to work in expressions.

Comment: I'm using expressions,  but if something like Automapper could help with this,  that would work too.  I'm working on an application I'm not familiar  with late in a project and was looking for an easy way to make some minor ancillary changes with as small a footprint as possible.